# Подсветка браузером полей формы на наличие сохраненной пары логин, пароль

Tags: html, javascript, css

Некоторые подсвечивают, некоторые нет. Но по сути это несколько нарушает в тех или иных случаях основную задумку относительно дизайна.

Есть ли средсва(css, javascript) как побороть подсветку полей? Кто сталкивался? есть ли решение, подскажите.

**UPD**: Для большей ясности

Когда юзер авторизовался на сайте, вылазит менеджер паролей, жмем сохранть. При следующей авторизации поля в форме уже подсвечены желтым ! В опере это наглядно можно увидеть!

**UPD2**: Вот на скринах до и после того как браузеру была дана команда сохранить пароль!

[image] [image]

Answer (score 1):

Используйте нормальный сброс стилей для всех элементов, включая элементы формы

```
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  outline:none;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  *vertical-align: middle;
}
button, input {
  line-height: normal;
  *overflow: visible;
}
button::-moz-focus-inner, input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
button,
input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: button;
}
input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
textarea {
  overflow: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Не то! Когда юзер авторизовался на сайте, вылазит менеджер паролей, жмем сохранть. При следующей авторизации поля уже подсвечены в форме! В опере это наглядно можно увидеть! Апну часть коммента в ответ.

Comment: Вы видимо о том, как Хром подсвечивает автозаполненные поля бледно-жёлтым?
В веб-инспекторе виден вендорный псевдокласс :-webkit-autofill, для которого и прописан этот самый бледно-жёлтый.
Но если задать вручную другой цвет для этого псевдо-класса, даже с большей специфичностью или с !important, браузер не реагирует. Так что, боюсь, придётся вас огорчить.

Comment: а это да, в хроме это не борется, разработчики отказались фиксить это ссылаясь на то, что это изменит привычное для пользователей поведение браузера